# Trying to pass value from TextInput in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image: screen]

This is what the screen looks like. Whatever name is typed will be shown after **"Hi,"** and rating part will be shown after **"is"**.

[image]

This is my code (Sorry did not know how to paste Native Code in snippet

[image]

The error I am getting. The funny thing is it works on React.js. But when I transferred to Native, it gives me this error so I think I am not doing something right, especially the **e.target.value** part.

Answer (score 0):

You are treating ReactNative as (Web) React. Please take a look at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-text-input (esp. the `onChangeText` prop).